# jquery css property top and left not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have following jquery code .

```
if(bubble.label != undefined){
                        console.log(bubble.label.attr('style'));
                        var bubbleStyle = bubble.label;
                        bubbleStyle.css({
                        color: 'red', 
                        left: 0+'px',
                        top: -660+'px'
                    });
}
```

In above code css property  color: 'red', applies but not left and top . I have tried it with giving position : 'absolute' but it still not works . Please help me on this .Thanks.

Comment: There might be a problem with the Selector. Provide full script and HTML or Create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
left: 0,
top: -660
```

instead of:

```
left: 0+'px',
top: -660+'px'
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Can you set up a demo to replicate your problem?

Comment: no there is no error , I can see changes with color property but not with top.

Answer (score 1):

use like this.Please make sure `position:absolute or relative` is set in css. Then only it works otherwise it not works

```
left: '0px',
top: '-660px'
```

Answer (score 0):

change the left and top to:

```
left: '0px',
top: '-660px'
```

Comment: Please make sure position:absolute or relative is set in css user3118011

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
bubbleStyle.css({
  color: "red", 
  left: "0",
  top: "-660px"
  });
```

Also, inspect the element to see if the inline style have been applied.

Comment: It should work http://jsfiddle.net/sSr6z/
Make sure the bubble element exists on page. Also, be aware that top is negative so the element might not be visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Considering bubble.label is a html `label` element try the following:

```
<label id="test">Testlabel</label>
```

Make sure the `label` is displayed `inline-block` and has a `relative` positioning.

```
#test {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

var bubbleStyle = jQuery('#test');

bubbleStyle.css({
    color: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    left: 0,
    top: 660,
});
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSf84/)

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery .css function updates the top value but the changes are not reflected in screen.

Use bubbleStyle.offset({top: -660}); It will update the top value both in DOM and screen.